# How to enable Hot-Reload in Mern Application using Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, mern, hot-reload

I got this problem and I can't solve it.
I am creating a MERN App and using Docker for the first time.

I have 2 docker containers. One in my Client and one in my Server.

**client** (React)

```coffee
FROM node:14-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**server** (nodeJS)

```coffee
FROM node:14-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

In My root folder i got this `docker-compose.yml` File.

```coffee
version: "3"
services:
  react-app:
    image: react-app
    build: ./client/
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  api-server:
    image: api-server
    build: ./server/
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4-bionic
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
networks:
  mern-app:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

In my server, I enabled hot reload using the -L flag in my script (in package.json).
But my React client won't enable Hot Reloading.

I hope someone has an answer for me.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Hmm. You should have hot reloading. Are you using Docker Desktop with WSL integration?

Comment: Yes, like i sad i am new to docker but i installed Docker today on my new PC and installed the WSL with a extra file.

Comment: Okay. What I did to get my hot reload working was to move the folder for my source code into the WSL folder. So if you are using Ubuntu, you can transfer it to your Ubuntu home by opening a file explorer and navigating to it. You can then run Docker from a WSL terminal in the copied WSL folder. Once the container is spun up, you should see hot reloading working.

Comment: okay so i tried this but it still dosent work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Hot-Reload inside Docker is a [common bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879) due to webpack configuration. It was solved [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879#issuecomment-1070466261) by setting `performance` flag as `false` so polling could work.

You can use this [React Hot-Reload Docker template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-react). I'm hoping you have already solved Node.js hot-reload inside Docker. If not, you can use this [Node.js Docker Hot-Reload Template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-nodejs).

PS: I created this template.

Comment: i dont know why but it still dosent work...